# Вычисление коэффициента корреляции в pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Нужно рассчитать парную корреляцию для некоторых столбцов.
Я сделала выборку по нужным мне столбцам, но при подсчете корреляции выводится ошибка:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-9583e45c056c> in <module>
  3 # с помощью метода corr:
  4 x = df[["temp","atemp", "hum","windspeed(mph)","windspeed(ms)","cnt"]].values
----> 5 x.corr()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'corr'
```

Вот код который я использую:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bikes_rent.csv')
x = df[["temp","atemp", "hum","windspeed(mph)","windspeed(ms)","cnt"]].values
x.corr()
```

Я знаю, что можно сделать вот таким способом:

```
df.iloc[:,7:13].corr()
```

Но почему не работает первый способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.values` у вас лишнее, `corr()` - метод `Pandas.DataFrame`, а после `.values` у вас получается чистый `numpy.ndarray`, у которого нет такого метода. Вот так будет работать:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bikes_rent.csv')
x = df[["temp","atemp", "hum","windspeed(mph)","windspeed(ms)","cnt"]] # убрал .values
x.corr()
```

Но если вы хотите посчитать корреляции именно на `numpy.ndarray` полученном через `df.values`, то можно так: `np.corrcoef(df.values)`